# How can I create a row matrices of large dimension by a code?

Tags: matrix, variable

I am trying to figure out how to create a function that can create the row matrix pattern below.

```
co = {{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, ...., a100}};
```

Comment: Please give more details. Do you really want a matrix of symbols with just one row? Or is your pattern the 1st row in a larger matrix?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are asking, but I'm willing to guess it might be

```
matrix[name_String, max_Integer?Positive] := 
  {Array[Symbol[name <> ToString[#]] &, max]}
```

Then

```
matrix["a", 10]
```

> `{{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10}}`

Comment: If this isn't the answer to your question, please edit the question and give us more detail about what you really want.

Comment: Thank you very much  m_goldberg you gave the answer for what is need thank you

Comment: @bhaskar. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear quite what you seek.  But if it is a $100 \times 100$ matrix:

```
co=Table[RandomReal[],{100},{100}]
```

If it is a $100 \times 1$ matrix:

```
co=Table[RandomReal[],{100},{1}]
```